# how to compute tile row from latitude in mercator projection

Tags: mapserver, tiles, worldwind, mercator

I work on google tile images. I want to compute a tile row from its latitude. How can I do that. I know that tile system cover all of the earth from -85 latitude to 85 latitude. 4 tiles exists at the first level. Google uses mercator projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openstreetmap uses the same tile numbering as Google, so you can use their formulas:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames